# Can't solve a probability - expected value question

Tags: probability

It doesn't seems like a hard question, but I can't get the correct answer. maybe I got one of the basic steps wrong?

The question:
A box contains 5 balls, numbered 1 to 5. I.e., {1,2,3,4,5}.

**first step**: randomly choose a ball, and color that ball in **black** along with all of the balls with numbers that are smaller than the first ball number.
(If we randomly drew ball number 3 then we color balls 1,2,3 in black.)

The rest of the balls - we color in **white**.

**second step**: we choose again a random ball, what is the expected value of the number of balls with the same color as the ball we drew?

I used conditional probability and got 2.6, the answer should be 3.4 (homework question).

What I did was to calculate the probability of drawing a black ball (3/5) 
and a white ball (2/5) and

$EN=\sum_0^5 nP(n=N)=\sum_0^5 nP(N=n│2nd-black)P(2nd-black) + \sum_0^5 nP(N=n│2nd-white)P(2nd- white)$

Now for $n=1,...,5$ each  $P(N=n│2nd-black)=1/5$

and for white - $n=1,...,4$ each $P(N=n│2nd-white)=1/5$ as well (because they depend on the first ball number, and it's random 1/5).

Calculated all and got 2.6, the paper says 3.4.
Can't locate my error.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since enumerating is not too demanding, we can first have a try at it. Let us look at all the possibilities **after** the first step. We can have
$$
BWWWW,\\
BBWWW,\\
BBBWW,\\
BBBBW,\\
BBBBB,
$$
where $B$ stands for a black ball and $W$ for a white one. As you mentionned, each of these is equally likely with probability $1/5$. Let $N$ be the number of mathcing balls and let $X$ be the number of black balls in the urn.

Now let's, for example, compute $N$ in the second case, that is we will compute $E[N~|~ X=2]$. There is a $2/5$ probability that we draw a black ball, and in that case $N=2$. There is also a $3/5$ probability that we draw a white one, making $N=3$. Together, this gives
$$
E[N~|~ X=2]=2\frac{2}{5}+3\frac{3}{5}=\frac{13}{5}.
$$
I leave it to you to compute
$$
E[N~|~ X=1]=E[N~|~ X=4]=\frac{17}{5}\\
E[N~|~ X=3]=\frac{13}{5}\\
E[N~|~ X=5]=\frac{25}{5}
$$

Putting these together, combined with the fact that they are equally likely, we get
$$
E[N]=\frac{1}{5}\left( \frac{17}{5}+\frac{13}{5}+\frac{13}{5}+\frac{17}{5}+\frac{25}{5}\right)=\frac{85}{25}=3.4
$$

To get a more general approach, let $N$ and $X$ be as above. We use $n$ starting balls instead of $5$. 
$$
\begin{align}
E[N]&=[E[N~|~X]],\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[N~|~X=k]P(X=k),\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k\frac{k}{n}+(n-k)\frac{n-k}{n}\right) \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}
$$
This simplifies to $\frac{1}{3}\frac{2n^2+1}{n}$, there may be a clever way to get it faster.

Comment: Fantastic, I though about using conditional probability on X, but just didnt knew how. didnt noticed that for each K, there is only two possible values of N - for black and white balls. but - can you tell me what went wrong with my way of solving it? conditional probability on the ball color?

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved it for the specific example case of drawing the number 3 ball originally, but the homework question wants the answer *not* assuming any particular value of the original ball.

Comment: I calculated the black ball and white ball with conditional probability aswell, conditioned on K (number of the first ball)...but maybe I did it wrong

Comment: OK.  When you gave the (3/5) and (2/5) as numbers, I guess you meant them as examples too, instead of as the only numbers you were looking at.  Should have read more carefully, I guess.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have part of it.  However you can't just use the expected number of black balls for the $2^{nd}$ part of your calculation. Also you may be getting tripped up by the case with selecting ball #$5$ on your 1st drawing.  As you already saw the probability of any number of black balls before your second drawing is $\frac{1}{5}$.

Let's look at what happens if your $1^{st}$ drawing is #$1$.  Then you have $1$ black ball for your $2^{nd}$ drawing.  For the case of #$1$ look at your $2^{nd}$ drawing.  There's a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of a black ball, with $1$ other balls matching it.  There's a $\frac{4}{5}$ chance of a white with $4$ others matching it.  Recall that there's a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance for this entire paragraph.

Continue in this way, but pay careful attention to what happens when you choose ball #$5$ on your first drawing.